# app out of proportion with android system webview

Tags: android, html, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, android-webview

at the last update of android system webview my APP (SPA) resolution is out of proportion.
we try to change use-scalable and more elements but nothing help.

any ideas ?
tnx,
sahar

Comment: What do you mean? Is your app to big?

Comment: If your application does not have MFP SDK do you see the same issue? ie, if you were to try with a simple Cordova project do you see the same issue?

Comment: hi steven, the HTML hugh and not customise to the screen

Comment: hi Vivin, we transfer to clean cordova and its excellent, also open PMR but there are no answers yet